# AngularJS code in a

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS and managed to get this to work. Can I get some feedback if this is done in an "Angular way?"

The DataResults Service just fetches some JSON data and will eventually have more methods that will process it. The part I am most curious about is the controller. It waits for the service to complete and then and then brings the data in scope. The HTML does some stuff with it, but is not relevant for this.

Thanks for your time

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp ", []);
myApp.factory("DataResults",function($http) {
  var data = [];

  var promise = $http.get("/js/data.json").
    success(function(d, status, headers, config) {
      data= _.compact(d);
    }).
    error(function(d, status, headers, config) {
      return "Error!";
    });

  promise.getData= function() {
    return data;
  };
  /* More methods */

  return promise;
});

/* Controllers */
myApp.controller("DataSearchCtrl", ["$scope", "DataResults", function($scope, DataResults) {
  DataResults.then(function() {
    $scope.data = DataResults.getData();
  });
}]);
```

Edit: I can't comment. Yes it does work.

Comment: does this code work ?

Comment: I think the $q library is designed to deal with promises and deference. But it looks vaguely like Angular ;)

Comment: Yes, this code does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep this is the Angular way!  However, I'd like to suggest some modifications.

With your current implementation, each time you inject `"DataResults"` into a controller, you will be making the `$http.get` request, on page load.  What happens when you need to add different `$http.get` functions?
I would inject the `$q` service into your `"DataResults"` factory, which will allow you greater flexibility. Using the `$q` service with the Deferred API, you not only return a promise, but the promise is resolved with the value itself.

Updated factory:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp ", []);
myApp.factory("DataResults",function($http,$q) {

return {  
  getJsonData: function(){ 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("/js/data.json").
      success(function(d, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(_.compact(d));
      }).
      error(function(d, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(d);
      }); 
    return deferred.promise;
  },
  getSomeOtherData: function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("/js/data.json").
      success(function(d, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(_.compact(d));
      }).
      error(function(d, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(d);
      }); 
    return deferred.promise;
  }  
};

});
```

updated Controller:

```
myApp.controller("DataSearchCtrl", ["$scope", "DataResults", 
 function($scope, DataResults) {

  $scope.initializePage = function(){
    DataResults.getJsonData().then(function(jsonData) {
      $scope.data = jsonData;
    });
  };

  $scope.loadTheOtherData = function(){
    DataResults.getSomeOtherData().then(function(someOtherData){
        $scope.otherData = someOtherData;
    });
  }; 
}]);
```

Answer (score -2):

I find that I often end up having to put $scope.$digest() in my controllers. Especially after setting some data like in your case of $scope.data = DataResults.getData(). In dev, we find that the situation did not come up often, (it must be related to timing), but in our production run of the code, we often saw missing data, and had to go back and put in $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest().